# Vue dynamic form with dynamic feedback

Tags: javascript, validation, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a case where I want to create a form in Vue based on an external JSON response dictating the form fields and feedback based on the choices made in the form.

This is a snippet of the JSON question-format I had in mind:

```
{
      "questionId": 23,
      "questionText": "Do you need help completing this questionnaire?",
      "questionName": "need-help",
      "answerType": "radio",
      "answers": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "answerText": "Yes",
          "answerFeedbackType": "error",
          "answerFeedback": "At the moment we cannot complete the intake procedure. Please contact us by sending an e-mail and we'll help you towards your subscription."
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "answerText": "No"
        }
      ]
    },
```

At the moment I pass this data to a Question component where I have props for each key of the data object. This is loaded from my Form component where I load in the JSON and loop though all questions. How should I go about determining whether to show a notification when the user clicks on an option where there is a feedbacktype of 'error' and also detect whether the user has actually filled in every field?

Comment: I got some minor progress on this. From the question-component I emit the answerObject back to the form on change. In the Form component I evaluate the answerFeedback and I plan to pass this data to a notification component.

Comment: I solved this in another way: I created a Feedback component that I place at each question in my loop. From the Question component I evaluate each onChange event and detect the feedbacktext and/or feedbacktype of the answer and update the props I pass to the Feedback component.